# Are there any Objective-C web frameworks?

Tags: objective-c, web-services, rest

Are there any Objective-C web frameworks? The only frameworks I've found is frothkit.

I'm primary looking for a way to write RESTful json web services in Objective-C.

Comment: it would be very interesting if Objective-C got used for more than just Mac/iphone dev.

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer I've worked on Linux-based ObjC software for salary before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GNUStepWeb](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/GNUstepWeb) is a web framework based on the Objective-C version of NeXT's WebObjects (Apple's WebObjects being Java only), but it has no particular support for JSON. It's certainly possible to get it to write JSON data, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do REST, but [SudzC](http://sudzc.com/) will generate an Objective-C web services proxy for invoking a web service.  They recently upped the documentation and sample code specific to the WSDL that you point it to or upload.  Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you from just using a JSON C library to handle the JSON stuff. Heck if you were feeling adventurous you could even write it yourself.